# Why does printing an IntegerField field does not give me a number? [Django]

Tags: django, sqlite, field

Having following field declared in my model:

```
info_number_of_views = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=0, null=False)
```

Whenever I am trying to print or log it with following command:

```
print('queried_model_of_particular_user.info_number_of_views: ' + str(queried_model_of_particular_user.info_number_of_views))
```

Instead of a number, I do receive that kind of an output:

```
queried_model_of_particular_user.info_number_of_views: (<django.db.models.fields.IntegerField>,)
```

Comment: Show us the code where you are fetching `queried_model_of_particular_user`. It looks like `info_number_of_views` is a list or tuple and not a field value, which is why it isn't rendering as you would expect.

Comment: queried_model_of_particular_user = ModelOfParticularPerson.objects.get(user=self.request.user)

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `str`

```
print('queried_model_of_particular_user.info_number_of_views: ' + queried_model_of_particular_user.info_number_of_views)
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been solved.
In the declaration of the field, by the mistake, I have also typed an extra ',' character.

It looked like this:

```
info_number_of_views = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=0, null=False),
```

A simple removal of it solved the problem.

```
info_number_of_views = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=0, null=False)
```